# Scripting memory not matching utterances on botium-cli

Tags: testing, chatbot

I am using botium-cli 0.0.40 and I have the following convo file (AGE.convo.txt):

```
#me
what is your age?

#bot
AGEA_UTT
```

There is also a utterance file (AGEA_UTT.utterances.txt):

```
AGEA_UTT
['I am $months months old.']
['I am $years years old.']
['I am 5 years old.']
```

For an answer: ['I am 5 years old.'] it passes. But for ['I am 6 years old.'] it fails:

> TranscriptError: Error: convos/AGE.convo.txt: Expected bot response
>   (on Line 4: #me - what is your age?  ) "['I am 6 years old.']" to
>   match one of "['I am $months months old.'],['I am $years years
>   old.'],['I am 5 years old.']"

Is it a bug? Do I have to change any Botium settings? The wiki doesn't mention any need for that: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/Botium-Scripting#scripting-memory

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the *SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY* capability to *true* to enable the memory.

**Attention: the build you mentioned doesn't yet allow scripting memory expressions in utterances! This is part of the next build scheduled for upcoming Monday!**

Comment: Nice, but this capability is not listed yet in the capabilities list here: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/Botium-Configuration#capabilities

Comment: latest build of botium-cli (0.0.41) is running. it includes botium-core 1.4.3 which supports scripting expressions in utterances lists. Wiki updated as well :-)

Comment: I've updated botium-cli to 0.0.41 and added to my botium.json "SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY": true but my tests still give the same results.

Comment: The brackets in your utterances ([', ']) are making the regular expression checker, which Botium uses for scripting expressions, fail - they have special meaning in regular expressions. Is there a special reason for those brackets there ?

Comment: Yes.. my bot answers a list of messages for each input message, so I have to check them all.

Comment: I think you can just remove the brackets from the utterances file. Still don't get it why your bot returns something in brackets ...

Comment: It is how I made my REST WS answer multiple intents. For a messaging platform it would send this lists of messages. Eg. for the input message "How are you? What is your name?" the answer would be two messages ['I am fine thanks.', 'My name is KINO and you?']. How would you approach that?

Comment: So I assume you are using the SimpleRest-Connector - if there are multiple texts returned (ie: the JSONPath resolves to an array), those output texts will be processed as individual "#bot" messages by Botium. That's how I would do it.

Comment: Yes, I am using SimpleRest-Connector. I don't know how for one request to my web-service I answer multiple responses to use more than one message in the #bot, so I did this list thing with [] as a default Python to string for a list does.

Comment: ok, I understand. But if you just remove the brackets in the utterances file, it will work for now. I added an item to our project backlog to deal with brackets in a more stable way.

Comment: I've tried without brackets and it works. When I use SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY and brackets without any $variable, it also works. The only combination that does not work is when you put brackets together with $variables. This behavior is unpredictable for other users that does not know the internals of botium.

Comment: Absolutely. That's why I classified it as bug and added it to our backlog. The SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY will be very likely changed soon to be enabled by default, currently it is somehow experimental.

Comment: The latest Botium Core, Botium Bindings and Botium CLI builds include the fix for this buggy behaviour

Comment: Very nice Florian.. tested and working! Version 0.0.42 for future reference.