# Botium scripting memory: Expected bot response not matched

Tags: testing, bots, chatbot

I am getting the following error when using Botium:

> TranscriptError: Error: GetNewGetDeleteGet/Line 27: Expected bot
>   response (on Line 20: #me - getID  ) "99 | This is a test" to match
>   one of "$id | This is a test"
>       at async.waterfall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/Convo.js:160:25)

Convo File:

```
#me: getID
#bot: $id | This is a test
```

To start Botium I do: `sudo botium-cli run mochawesome`
I already fired up this command: `export BOTIUM_ENABLE_MEMORY=true`

Any ideas?
Botium should accept the answer of the bot and save the 99 into the variable $id, shouldn't it?

Edit: After adding SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY=true to the config file

convo.txt:

```
#me
get
#bot default
*Hier sind deine Erinnerungen:*

Keine Notizen, oder alles erledigt.
```

Error:

```
TranscriptError: Error: GetNewGetDeleteGet/Line 11: error waiting for bot SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*Hier sind deine Erinnerungen:* Keine Notizen, oder alles erledigt./: Nothing to repeat at String.match (native) at utterances.forEach.expected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/Convo.js:359:38) at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at Convo._fillScriptingMemory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/Convo.js:353:18) at scriptingEvents.onBotStart.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/Convo.js:256:22) at <anonymous>
```

[Dialogflow shows the answer like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVleE.png)

My Code sends it out like that:

```
{'fulfillmentText': '*Hier sind deine Erinnerungen:*\n\nKeine Notizen, oder alles erledigt.'}
```

Edit 2:

[After removing the *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QHD3.png)

[Convo.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0sJd.png)

Edit 3:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpH8Y.jpg) [Full error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTcK2.png)

Edit 4:
[Verbose Log](https://pastebin.com/nG71pB6W)

Comment: Could you send the whole log, not just the error?

Comment: sure, whole log has been added

Comment: oh that was included in the first screenshot as well.. hmm what exactly do you need and how do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- The environment variable to set is *BOTIUM_SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY*
- Usually, when running a command with *sudo* you will loose the environment variables. You can add the capability *SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY* to the *botium.json* file instead.

Comment: Thank you. Updated my post.

Maybe the bot gets the error because of \n\n ?

Comment: Scripting memory doesn't play well with regular expressions right now (same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153962/scripting-memory-not-matching-utterances-on-botium-cli)).

Comment: It means that the "*" are interpreted as regular expression character by Botium, and that's why it fails. And in your case, the \n\n might be a problem as well. It is in our backlog and will be solved very soon.

Comment: Removed the "*"

One other test is now successfull.
The other is showing: 

TranscriptError: Error: GetNewGetDeleteGet/Line 27: Expected bot response (on Line 20: #me - get ) "Hier sind deine Erinnerungen: Notiz: 104 | This is a test reminder" to match one of "Hier sind deine Erinnerungen: Notiz: undefined | This is a test reminder"

Which is right - $id is undefined, as I want the bot to save the Id 104 into the variable. Why cant the bot save the id?

Comment: attached two Screenshots.

Comment: The reason is most likely that the pipe sign is another special character for regular expression. You did everything right, your sample code looks perfect. please be patient for some days, one of the next builds will include a fix for this.

Comment: The latest Botium Core, Botium Bindings and Botium CLI builds include the fix for this buggy behaviour

Comment: ran into some errors while updating.

after downgrading to npm 6.9.0 I only got one error left: Failed at the botium-core postinstall script license-checker -> licenses-3rdparty.txt

Is that an issue with my setup or with botium?

Comment: to get rid of this problem please run "npm i -g license-checker" - is an issue we already recorded and will fix in the next build.

Comment: I have been frustrated but am now revisiting this one. Installing went flawlessly. First tests are valid. Thank you for your continuous support. 

Some of my commands start with ! - when botium starts the convo, it doesn't send the exclamation mark (it is captured inside the convo file). Can I enable that somehow?

Comment: Good question. The ! is currently used as negation in BotiumScript. But I consider this to be a bug, it should be possible to use the literal exclamation mark as well. I add it to our backlog, usually we resolve bugs like this very quick.

Comment: Nice, thanks!

One last thing for now: 
I have added a picture (Edit 3) to the original post. You can see my botium.json, the convo file and an error.
Any idea why the responses dont match according to the error? The variable $id should be filled with 183 and it should match, shouldnt it?

Comment: Please add the "--verbose" switch to botium-cli and attach the log output (take care to remove sensitive information first).

Comment: Attached the log output (Edit 4: Verbose Log)

Comment: Please try with the latest build (from yesterday) - I assume this has been fixed with this commit: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/commit/ba84da3f6e51caadfeb9914a4358e4c6c4584c41

Comment: i wasn't able to update. reinstalled linux, installed (npm and) botium-cli 0.0.48. downloaded recent convo.txt and botium.json. Still the same error :(

Comment: still getting the error :( 
have you been able to reproduce?

Comment: This is a bug with multiline statement. I added it to our backlog, will work on it in the next days.